# Can't get the walrus operator to work (Python double list comprehension)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, python-3.8, walrus-operator

This list comprehension does not work:

```
buy_prices = [(buylow := round(0.997 + ii/10000.0, 5), max(jj, buylow)) for jj in [buylow, 0.9982] for ii in range(21)]
```

`NameError: name 'buylow' is not defined`

This one doesn't either:

```
buy_prices = [(buylow, max(jj, buylow)) for jj in [buylow := round(0.997 + ii/10000.0, 5), 0.9982] for ii in range(21)]
```

`SyntaxError: assignment expression cannot be used in a comprehension iterable expression`

How am I supposed to do this? Or do I just have to do the round calculation for `buylow` twice?

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you are trying to do ... Why don't you just give us a regular for loop version to make it explicit?

Comment: Anyway, the problem is probably the *order* of your for-clauses, you are trying to use `buylow` in the outer for clause but *that variable isnt defined*. Maybe switch the order? Again, only guessing, since you haven't told us what you want

Comment: So, in the first one, what value do you **expect*, `for jj in [buylow, 0.9982]` to have? `buylow` is defined in the mapping expression, the equivalent of the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend not using nested list comprehensions, since that is not very readable to many people.

Instead maybe something like this:

```py
buy_prices = list()
for ii in range(21):
    buylow = round(.997 + ii / 10000, 5)
    for jj in (buylow, .9982):
        buy_prices.append((buylow, max(jj, buylow))
```

Comment: "You can't use the walrus operator in a list comprehension." You absolutely can. But I agree the OP should just use a for-loop

Comment: I guess I just assumed that's what the error message meant since it was fairly explicit. I've edited the answer to omit the part about the walrus.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote. That error is referring to the iterable expression part, so `[<mapping expr> for <whatever> in <iterable_expression>]` and I believe it only applies to the left-most because the scoping would be ambiguous so they just decided not to allow it (the left-most `<iterable_expression>` is evaluated in the enclosing scope that *contains* the list comprehesnio, not the local scope of the list comprehension)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you for the explanation :)